# Building proper tree

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree, huffman-code, algebraic-data-types

So, I have that Huffman tree, that is used for encoding strings. And I have defined the function `plant`, but I am not sure whether my tree is not tilting too much only to the one side. Here is my code:

```
data HuffTree
    = Leaf Char
    | HuffTree |*| HuffTree     
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

`|*|` is an infix Constructor.

```
plant :: [(Char,Int)] -> HuffTree
plant [(x,y)] = (Leaf x)
plant ((x,y):xs) = plant xs |*| (Leaf x)
```

For me, it looks one-sided and hence it really doesn`t implies the encoding idea, since not being a real binary tree. How could I turn it into a regular binary tree?

Comment: Your datatype isn't really suitable for representing Huffman trees because you don't store frequencies anywhere. Frequencies can be implicit at nodes (which is inefficient) but you must have the frequency at the leaves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not constructing the Huffman tree correctly.  The process is supposed to go like this:

1. Turn all the source symbols into single-element huffman trees
2. Pair each source symbol up with its frequency into a big list of tree/frequency pairs.
3. If there is just one tree/frequency pair left, that tree is your Huffman tree.
4. Else remove the two trees/frequency pairs with the lowest freqyency, combine the trees and add the frequencies to make a new tree/frequency pair, and add it back to the list.
5. Goto 3.

So I'd change it to `plant :: [(HuffTree,Int)] -> HuffTree`.  In the second case I'd sort the elements, pluck off the first two, combine them, then call `plant` recursively.  You might also want to swith to `(Int,HuffTree)` pairs so that you can use the default sort implementation.  You'd also need to add `Ord` to your `HuffTree` deriving clause.